# How can I update a property of MonoBehaviour's script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `MarkBehaviour` class that contains a property called `markCount`. Depending on `markCount`, I will select the sprite on the `Update()` function.

But when I call the `setMark()` function from other behaviour class, I have logged the `markCount` property in 2 functions below, but the `markCount` property on `Update()` function was not changed. It was changed only in `setMark()` function.

```
public class MarkBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    public int markCount;

    void Start(){
           markCount = 0;
    }

    void Update () {    
        Debug.Log ("mark setted from other class" + markCount);
        int cal = calculate (markCount);
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = numberSpriteArray[cal];
    }

    public void setMark(int mark){
        Debug.Log ("manual set mark from other class, set " + markCount);
        markCount = mark;
    }
}
```

How can I change it?

Code of the other class that calls `setMark()` function:

```
public class GameoverBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject mark;

    void Start () {
        int markCount = getMark ();

        Instantiate (mark, new Vector3(2.3f,-0.5f,0), gameObject.transform.localRotation);
        MarkBehaviour mBS = (MarkBehaviour) mark.GetComponent<MarkBehaviour>();
        mBS.setMark (markCount);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

   // for example set it to 30
    int getMark(){
       return 30;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are setting/logging in the same instance of the MarkBehavior class?

Comment: Yes of course. I have added the code of class that call SetMark() function! Please help me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

When you run this line of code:

```
MarkBehaviour mBS = (MarkBehaviour) mark.GetComponent<MarkBehaviour>();
```

You are actually saying, find the MarkBehaviour in the prefab `mark`. This won't work because prefab has not been instantiated, only a clone of the prefab has been.

---

You have two good ways of doing this.

#### Solution 1

You can Instantiate the object then [**SendMessage**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html):

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(mark, new Vector3(2.3f,-0.5f,0), gameObject.transform.localRotation) as GameObject;

g.SendMessage("setMark", markCount);
```

Notice I am keeping a reference `g` to the instantiated object so that I can use SendMessage on it.

---

#### Solution 2

You can store a reference to the [**Component**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) `MarkBehaviour` attached to the GameObject.

```
private MarkBehaviour markObj;

GameObject g = Instantiate(mark, new Vector3(2.3f,-0.5f,0), gameObject.transform.localRotation) as GameObject;
```

Once you have the reference to the GameObject `g` you can then use the `GetComponent()` function.

```
markObj = g.GetComponent<MarkBehaviour>();
markObj.setMark(markCount);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that you are not creating a proper reference to the mark instantiation.

replace this :

```
Instantiate (mark, new Vector3(2.3f,-0.5f,0), gameObject.transform.localRotation);
```

with this :

```
mark = Instantiate (mark, new Vector3(2.3f,-0.5f,0), gameObject.transform.localRotation) as GameObject;
```